# Branching project with branches of other projects int TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, branch, clearcase

I have in my TFS collection 4 projects:

- External
- Internal
- Project A
- Project B

My External Project is where I store external libraries, not developed int he company.
My Internal Project is where I store internal libraries, developed in the company.
Project A and Project B are projects developed in the company.

Internal Project has dependencies on some libraries of External Projects. Project A and Project B has dependencies on some libraries of Internal and External Projects.

I want that Internal Project has dependency on the libraries of External that it uses. To make that work I branch those projects into Internal Project, like follows:

Internal Project

- internal

  1. Library 1...
- external

  1. Library ext 1...

External Project

- Library ext 1...

Project A

- project A
- internal

  1. Library 1...
- external

  1. Library ext 1...

Project B has similar structure to Project A. I want that once Internal Project has settled the references to External, when I set Project A references to Internal, automatically it references all the libraries in external also. I manage to make the references of External to Internal Project by branching the libraries I want to reference in the specific version I needed. This works fine, but when I try to branch all the Internal Project into Project A or Project B, TFS does not let me do it, because of the internal branches contained in Internal from External.

I'm newbie to TFS, and this structure was created when the company was using IBM Rational ClearCase. Probably this is not the correct way to organize my projects, or perhaps branching is not the way to make the references I want. If someone could help to make it work, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do this is to use binary dependencies.  Don't take a dependency on the source, but instead of the compiled binary.  You would check the various binaries (from External/Internal) that Project A needed into a lib folder into Project A, and setup your references to point to that path.

This way it gives Project A developers the flexibility to determine when they wish to update the version that they depend on (by checking in an updated binary).

An **even better** way is to have the External/Internal libraries publish their binaries via NuGet, and have Project A/B use NuGet to manage their dependencies.

Comment: These are projects of different kind of libraries, not all of them could be compiled into binary objects, and there is need to use directly the source code sometimes and not binaries itself.

Comment: if you just want the source for debugging you can include the PDBs in the lib folder and it accomplishes the same thing.  for the ones that aren't binaries what are they?

Comment: Sometimes are JavaScript libraries or python ones, etc, that evolve during the time, but the different projects uses different versions of them.

Comment: That can all be handled via NuGet.it works with Javascript (Twitter Bootstrap is on there) and you can have it automatically maintain the version dependencies for you...